# Scala for comprehensions/loops and typed patterns

Tags: scala

According to section 6.19 of the Scala Language Specification this for loop:

```
for (e <-p) e'
```

is translated to:

```
p <- e.withFilter{case p => true; case _ => false}.foreach{case p => e′}
```

So, why this small program:

```
object ForAndPatterns extends App {
  class A()
  class B() extends A

  val list: List[A] = List(new A(), new B(), new B())

  for {b: B <- list}
    println(b)
}
```

gives this compilation error:

```
Error:(7, 13) type mismatch;
 found   : proves.ForAndPatterns.B => Unit
 required: proves.ForAndPatterns.A => ?
   for {b: B <- list}
```

when this expression:

```
list.withFilter{case a: B => true; case _ => false}.foreach{case b => println(b)}
```

gives no error.

Comment: http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.12/08-pattern-matching.html#irrefutable-patterns

Comment: `The translation scheme is as follows. In a first step, every generator p <- e, where p is not irrefutable for the type of e is replaced by`. This is a irrefutable pattern.

Comment: @pedrofurla No, `b: B` is not irrefutable for type `A`.

Comment: @Alexey "`p` is a typed pattern `x:T′`,  and `T'<:T`"

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Er... it's `T <: T'` (so in this case `A <: B`) and the other way around would make no sense.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Pattern is irrefutable for a type if all non-null values of the type match the pattern, and not all values of type `A` match `b: B`.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov Yeah sorry I copied that on mobile and it got mixed up. I actually was not aware this is a thing until now, just pasted the section which looks like it matches the pattern.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov why did you edit my question title? The problem occurs in for loops too.

Comment: @jmbeleta To make the question easier to find: "for" is generally not useful for search. I thought that for loops were just a specific case of for comprehensions, but now I see that's incorrect. Maybe write "for comprehensions/loops" or would you prefer the original title?

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov "for comprehensions/loops" is fine. By the way for me the name "for comprehensions" is incomprehensible.

Comment: @jmbeleta Edited. As for the name, a for comprehension used with lists is just a [list comprehension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_comprehension) which are called that in quite a few languages, so it's a natural enough generalization. F# calls a very similar concept "computation expressions", and Haskell "monad comprehensions" (but that's less general).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The translation you get from specification is actually

```
list.withFilter{case b: B => true; case _ => false}.foreach{case b: B => println(b)}
```

but it still compiles and works. It seems like Scala is losing the `case` and translating to

```
list.withFilter{case b: B => true; case _ => false}.foreach{b: B => println(b)}
```

which would give the same error.

This turns out to be a known and old bug: https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/900.

Workaround provided there:

```
object Typed { def unapply[A](a: A) = Some(a) }

for { Typed(b: B) <- list } println(b)
```